# iPhone 4s wifi problem

Tags: wifi, iphone

My iPhone is no longer on I'm using it as an iPod for now but I cant connect to the wifi ; like the wifi is greyed out. I restarted and rest it , it's not on air plane mode or anything. How do I fix my phone?

Answer (score 2):

that is a trick you may tried it out, it's work for me for now.

1) use air dryer heat up your phone at the top part(you can aim on the headphone jack) until you iphone shown up the temperature screen.

2) When the temperature screen show up , turn off you phone (caution! the phone is very HOT).

3)After it is off pit it into a zip lock bag.

4)Let it rest for 1-2min and then put into the freezer for 30Min

5)When you take it out let it remain in zip lock bag and turn on the phone ( it may show battery low screen. If it's happen wait for a while and try turn it on again)

6) You are done!! you fix your wifi.

It will grayed out again whenever you update to a newer version of ios, so if that happen redo this proccess. So far it work for me, you may give it a try..

Comment: This seems to be a rather dangerous procedure...

Comment: @patrix if we have no choices , that will be an option then...

Comment: @patrix Well, it is a little dangerous. Still you can skip the freezer part and just let it slowly cool down while it is off. I have successfully performed this "fix" (without the freezer) many times. However, it is not a permanent fix... Moreover, I would say that heating you phone that much and regularly, will slowly reduce your battery's efficiency

Answer (score 0):

So you can see the wi-fi networks list but you can't connect to your specific wi-fi or...?

To be sure it's not some weird problem with iOS you should probably just "Restore iPhone..." with iTunes and check for an iOS update while you're at it.

[from Apple's instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)